# Multiple maven generate-sources

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have two plugins generating Java files. One generates code from a WSDL file and the other from an XSD schema file. Only the code from the schema is generated.

If I have separate Eclipse projects for each plugin, then all the source code is generated correctly. But I want to have in one project both plugins generating the code.

Here is my pom file:

```
<plugins>

<!-- generate Java classes from schema files (binding files optional) -->
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xsd_phase</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/xsd/</bindingDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
                <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/src/generated/java/</generateDirectory>
                <generatePackage>com.abc.xyz.jaxb</generatePackage>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <episode>false</episode>
                <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


<!-- generate Java classes from wsdl files -->
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsdl_phase</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <packageName>com.abc.xyz.ws</packageName>
                <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/target/src/generated/java/</sourceDestDir>
                <xnocompile>false</xnocompile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 3):

Just include both in the `build/plugins` configuration of your project. There is nothing in the `POM` format preventing a binding of two different goals from different plugins to the same phase (`generate-sources` in your case).

The only caveat you have to be mindfull of is that, when two executions are bound to the same phase, they will be executed in the order they are defined in the POM. In other words, if you were to copy-paste your snippet into the POM as it stands, during `generate-sources`, the `xsd_phase` would run first, and then `wsdl_phase`.